# Can I use redux in a component to avoid prop drilling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Let's say I have this structure

```
 _______________
| HomeContainer |
 ---------------
        |         _______________   
        |-------- | ComponentX |
                   --------------
                        |       _____________
                        |------ | ComponentZ |
                                --------------   _____________
                                      |---------|  User      |
                                                 -------------
```

And the following code for user

```js
const User = (props) => {
  return <h1>{props.user.name}</h1>
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    user: state.auth.user // I have an auth reducer mapped in the store
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(User)
```

Can I use `Redux` to avoid having to pass the user to `ComponentX` and `ComponentZ` even if `User` is just a component and not a container?

What solution `Redux` provides to prop drilling?

Comment: Yes you can use Redux to avoid prop drilling. You could also use React Context API, might be an easier solution

Comment: @Jayce444 Is it ok to mix redux with the context api. don't they have similar purposes?

Comment: It might be worth taking a step back and thinking about what you're trying to achieve with Redux. Are you hoping to persist that slice of state across different views of an app? Relevant to your concern is this article ["You might not need Redux"](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367) by Dan Abramov. Another option is `useReducer()` as a React hook.

Comment: @Federico there is definitely a lot of overlap between them. In terms of which one you should pick, that's a loaded question. Best to do a bunch of research on each and look up comparisons between the two

Comment: I would highly recommend [recoil](https://recoiljs.org/). It's pretty new, also developed by facebook engineers, and skips a lot of the boilerplate of Contexts or Redux.

Comment: @usrrname I think for the project I'm working on Redux is justified. Still the question remains if Redux is well suited for avoiding prop dirlling and in what folder those kind of components should be placed since they are not pure components and they are not containers. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Federico In my short experience, no, Redux comes with a whole bunch of boilerplate in terms of 1. having to define action types and then reference them again when the action is defined. 2. having to pass props down the component hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you only need to use connect function from react-redux it accept two arguments the first is the state the second will be the dispatch the actions like the code down bellow.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { MyAuthActions } from '../some/actions/files' //<--- my action file

const User = ({ user }) => <h1 onClick={myActionFunction}>{user.name}</h1> //<---- myActionFunction was created in my action created file dispatch

const state = ({ auth }) => ({ user: auth.user })
const dispatch = dispatch => bindActionCreators(MyAuthActions, dispatch)

export default connect(state, dispatch)(User)
```

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks